# Write a function to cycle through subsets by adding/deleting elements

Tags: c, algorithm

Problem: Start with a set `S` of size 2n+1 and a subset `A` of `S` of size n. You have functions `addElement(A,x)` and `removeElement(A,x)` that can add or remove an element of `A`. Write a function that cycles through all the subsets of `S` of size n or n+1 using just these two operations on `A`.

I figured out that there are (2n+1 choose n) + (2n+1 choose n+1) = 2 * (2n+1 choose n) subsets that I need to find. So here's the structure for my function:

```
for (int k=0; k<2*binomial(2n+1,n); ++k) {
    if (k mod 2) {
        // somehow choose x from S-A
        A = addElement(A,x);
        printSet(A,n+1);
    } else
        // somehow choose x from A
        A = removeElement(A,x);
        printSet(A,n);
    }
}
```

The function `binomial(2n+1,n)` just gives the binomial coefficient, and the function `printSet` prints the elements of `A` so that I can see if I hit all the sets.

I don't know how to choose the element to add or remove, though. I tried lots of different things, but I didn't get anything that worked in general.

For n=1, here's a solution that I found that works:

```
for (int k=0; k<6; ++k) {
    if (k mod 2) {
        x = S[A[0] mod 3];
        A = addElement(A,x);
        printSet(A,2);
    } else
        x = A[0];
        A = removeElement(A,x);
        printSet(A,1);
    }
}
```

and the output for `S = [1,2,3]` and `A=[1]` is:

```
[1,2]
[2]
[2,3]
[3]
[3,1]
[1]
```

But even getting this to work for n=2 I can't do. Can someone give me some help on this one?

Comment: Which operations are allowed on set S?

Comment: I don't fully understand the imposed restrictions - what prevents us from generating all the possible combinations of n and n+1 elements (out of the total 2n+1 elements) and printing them out?

Comment: @Grigory: Because you can only add or remove one element at a time, and you can only use sets of size n or n+1. So you can't go from [1] to [2] or from [1,3] to [2].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a solution so much as it's another way to think about the problem.

Make the following graph:

- Vertices are all subsets of `S` of sizes `n` or `n+1`.
- There is an edge between `v` and `w` if the two sets differ by one element.

For example, for n=1, you get the following cycle:

```
 {1} --- {1,3} --- {3}
  |                 |
  |                 |
{1,2} --- {2} --- {2,3}
```

Your problem is to find a [Hamiltonian cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path):

> A Hamiltonian cycle (or Hamiltonian circuit) is a cycle in an
>   undirected graph which visits each vertex exactly once and also
>   returns to the starting vertex. Determining whether such paths and
>   cycles exist in graphs is the Hamiltonian path problem which is
>   NP-complete.

In other words, this problem is hard.

There are a handful of theorems giving sufficient conditions for a Hamiltonian cycle to exist in a graph (e.g. if all vertices have degree at least `N/2` where `N` is the number of vertices), but none that I know immediately implies that this graph has a Hamiltonian cycle.

You could try one of the myriad algorithms to determine if a Hamiltonian cycle exists. For example, from the wikipedia article on the [Hamiltonian path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem):

> A trivial heuristic algorithm for locating hamiltonian paths is to
>   construct a path abc... and extend it until no longer possible; when
>   the path abc...xyz cannot be extended any longer because all
>   neighbours of z already lie in the path, one goes back one step,
>   removing the edge yz and extending the path with a different neighbour
>   of y; if no choice produces a hamiltonian path, then one takes a
>   further step back, removing the edge xy and extending the path with a
>   different neighbour of x, and so on. This algorithm will certainly
>   find an hamiltonian path (if any) but it runs in exponential time.

Hope this helps.

---

**Good News**: Though the Hamiltonian cycle problem is difficult in general, this graph is very nice: it's bipartite and `(n+1)`-regular. This means there may be a nice solution for this particular graph.

**Bad News**: After doing a bit of searching, it turns out that this problem is known as the *Middle Levels Conjecture*, and it seems to have originated around 1980. As best I can tell, the problem is still open in general, but it has been computer verified for `n <= 17` (and I found a [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.4564) from 12/2009 claiming to verify `n=18`). These two pages have additional information about the problem and references:

- http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~west/openp/revolving.html
- http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/?q=op/middle_levels_problem

Comment: It's not necessarily true that the problem is hard because you've reduced it to Hamiltonian path.  It's only hard if you reduce Hamiltonian path to this problem.

Comment: I have solved very similar problem that can be presented as hamiltonian graph.
Problem and solution in comments: http://www.tablix.org/~avian/blog/archives/2009/06/entering_pin_without_confirmation/

Comment: @templatetypedef True enough. This graph is k-regular, which makes it somewhat special, so there may be a nice solution out there.

Comment: @ralu: I do not think these two problems are that similar (other than that each looks for a Hamiltonian cycle).

Comment: @PengOne: Only difference there is is that i generated all permutations, where he you have to generate all combinations. And yes I have currenly no idea how to solve this one.

Comment: Well, then that was a bullshit question to ask. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score -1):

This sort of thing is covered in Knuth Vol 4A (which despite Charles Stross's excellent Laundry novels is now openly available). I think you request is satisfied by a section of a monotonic binary gray code described in section 7.2.1.1. There is an online preprint with a PDF version at http://www.kcats.org/csci/464/doc/knuth/fascicles/fasc2a.pdf

Comment: I had thought of that, but the problem is that I can only use sets of sizes n and n+1. I couldn't get this to work, but if you can, then let me know!